# WUBI is only installing Ubuntu & not Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I've downloaded full image of Ubuntu GNOME 13.04 & extracted it to my laptop. Now whenever I am booting it using USB it is very well working but whenever I tried to install it using WUPBI it is only & only showing me Ubuntu...kubuntu ..options & not GNOME one & even if I select ubuntu option , it start to download meta data. Any Idea why it is happening..why GNOME is not installing.

Comment: which pc and os you are using?Wubi doesn't support on devices which had UEFI firmware.

Answer (score 0):

use Yumi installer instead...
it will do the job for you...
worked well for me...

Answer (score 0):

Wubi only supports a specific list of options which are [hardcoded at the time it is built](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-installer/wubi/trunk/view/head:/data/isolist.ini).

For 13.04 it's:

- Ubuntu
- Kubuntu
- Mythbuntu
- Edubuntu
- Lubuntu
- Ubuntu Studio

For custom made distros, they need to also customize Wubi if they want to make it available, and this obviously hasn't been done.

So for you it's best to do a normal install - while there are ways to trick Wubi into installing an unsupported distro it's more effort than it's worth for most people.